# node-tesseract-ocr throwing cannot open input file: stdin error

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

**CODE:**

```
const tesseract = require("node-tesseract-ocr");

const config = {
    lang: "eng",
    oem: 1,
    psm: 3,
};

tesseract
.recognize("https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png", config)
.then((text) => {
    console.log("Result:", text);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

**ERROR:**

```
Command failed: tesseract stdin stdout -l eng --oem 1 --psm 3
read_params_file: Can't open 1
read_params_file: Can't open -psm
read_params_file: Can't open 3
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica
Cannot open input file: stdin
```

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

- Platform: Windows 11
- Node Version: v18.12.1
- Tesseract Version: 3.02

I am trying to extract text from images using NodeJS but getting this error what I am doing wrong here?

Is there any other reliable library available for extracting text from images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. tesseract will not work on a captcha.
2. you use archaic tesseract, but commands for the current version of the tesseract.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the installation is correct, type in a terminal "tesseract", if you get an error:
Check if the environments variables are correct:

1. Name: TESSDATA_PREFIX value: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata
2. Name: tesseract value: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe
3. In PATH variable add C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR

if you are using VSCode to run the script, restart the window (that works for me).